# Following MSDN tutorial - Windows Service not installing

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

So here I am again experiencing yet another MSDN fail. As usual, I've decided to learn how to write a Windows Service in C# and due to many tutorials offering incomplete or just poorly-written code, I've decided to use MSDN.

I've followed every step and my service will not install.

The page I'm following along with is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

and my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class WindowsService1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public WindowsService1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource", "MyNewLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");

        }

        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue.");
        }
    }
}
```

I've gone into developer command prompt, cd'd to the directory containing my .exe (the debug folder), and I've:

`installutil WindowsService1.exe` and also tried `installutil.exe WindowsService1.exe` but the installation always fails, with the following text:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>cd
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\ Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug
>
> C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsServ ice1\bin\Debug>installutil
>   WindowsService1.exe Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility
>   Version 4.0.30319.32559 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   asse mbly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly 'C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Window
>   sService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe'. Affected
>   parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService
>   1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsSe rvice1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe Installing
>   service Service1... Creating EventLog source Service1 in log
>   Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager
>   on compute r '.'. This operation might require other privileges. The
>   inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with
>   the fol lowing error message: Access is denied.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   asse mbly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>   Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe'. Affected
>   parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService
>   1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsSe rvice1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe Restoring event
>   log to previous state for source Service1.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.
>
> C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsServ ice1\bin\Debug>installutil
>   WindowsService1 Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility
>   Version 4.0.30319.32559 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Use rs\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\b
>   in\Debug\WindowsService1' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the  file specified..
>
> C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsServ ice1\bin\Debug>installutil
>   WindowsService1.exe Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility
>   Version 4.0.30319.32559 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   asse mbly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly 'C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Window
>   sService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe'. Affected
>   parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService
>   1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsSe rvice1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe Installing
>   service Service1... Creating EventLog source Service1 in log
>   Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager
>   on compute r '.'. This operation might require other privileges. The
>   inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with
>   the fol lowing error message: Access is denied.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   asse mbly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>   Rolling back assembly 'C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Wind
>   owsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe'. Affected
>   parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService
>   1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog    assemblypath
>   = C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsSe rvice1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe Restoring event
>   log to previous state for source Service1.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.
>
> C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsServ ice1\bin\Debug>

which also outputs an INSTALLLOG file into theDebug directory, which contains (the same info):

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager
>   on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges. The
>   inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with
>   the following error message: Access is denied.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager
>   on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges. The
>   inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with
>   the following error message: Access is denied.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\Users\Tommy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.InstallLog.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

So then I go back to MSDN. To see what to do if the installation fails, but instead I see this:

`If the service installs successfully, installutil.exe will report success.` There is no other information about what to do if the install fails.

---

I've spent days on this and I've followed over 8 tutorials, all of which have either incomplete or bad code (that doesn't work). So I finally decide to put my trust in MSDN again but as usual I'm left wondering what the hell is going on.

My user account has full read/write/exec permissions, is an administrator and I have checked Computer Management (> Services and Applications) and confirmed that my Windows Service is *not* listed there.

What do I do now? How do I create a Windows Service (that works)?

Comment: If your using windows vista or higher you should run the command prompt with 'Run as Administrator' - even if your account is already member of administrators

Comment: You should read about UAC and understand that just because you're in the Administrators group doesn't mean your session is running at that level.

Comment: Please run as administrator ...and in future try to keep your post simple and `short`

Comment: OK, so deleted my answer recommending topshelf, since it (rather oddly to my mind) seemed to be a negative vote magnet. Nonetheless, it's worth a look as a widely used and generally great way to host windows services: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

Comment: Run devloper cmd as admin and if it solved your issue mark the answer as solution and in future try to keep your post simple and short

Comment: I was running as administrator but I failed to mention that because I thought running as admin was just common sense.

Comment: @Sumeshk sinple and short? On this website? Yeah right! I'll never understand you people. First you say there's never enough detail but when there is it's "too much".

Comment: I think the point is that you dumped a lot of repetitive log information that clearly didn't add value. One copy is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
An exception occurred during the Install phase. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
```

Run your developer command prompt "as administrator". Being an administrator is not the same as running your processes as administrator.

From MSDN:

> On the Start menu or Start Page, open the shortcut menu for Developer Command Prompt, and then choose Run As Administrator.

Comment: I did this already. I did this from the beginning. Running as admin was just common sense and I didn't mention this because there are several things I _could_ have mentioned but didn't because apparently having detail in questions is frowned upon on this website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for repeating what the tutorial said. It turned out I was still wrong this time. I had originaly opened Command Prompt "run as admin" but then forgot to run developer command prompt as admin. Much appreciated, @ta.speot.is :)

Answer (score 1):

> An exception occurred during the Install phase. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on compute r '.'. This operation might require other privileges. The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the fol lowing error message: Access is denied.

The error says what the problem is: you don't have permission to install the service.

If the machine is a domain member, it's entirely possible that the local admin account doesn't have permissions required to install the service.

It's also possible that it's being blocked by AV software or that your service needs to be added to a whitelist. The possibilities are nearly endless, so you'll need to find out what the specific error is.

You might get more information from the Security Event Log. You can also try the sysinternals Process Monitor. It should show you what it's trying to do and what is failing.

> My user account has full read/write/exec permissions, is an administrator

If you're on a domain, you may need to be a domain admin.